# Hive table too many partitions

Tags: hive

```
use mydb;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table(
processed_date date,
source varchar(100) ,
table_name varchar(1000) ,
comments varchar(1000) ,
column varchar(255) 
)     
ROW FORMAT SERDE   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT   'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION  'hdfs://xxxxxx/xxxxxx/my_table ';
```

I have a table definition like this. And I am using a Spark program to insert some records into this table. The table has too many partitions in a very short span of time. And any query against the table is very slow.
How can I limit/reduce the number of partitions getting created.

Comment: The table is not partitioned. What do you mean by "partition"? Also, partitions' high number does not cause to the slowness directly. The slowness is directly affected by the resources underlying the mapreduce infrastructure.